# Setting up Custom class Object as Key/value in Apache Geode

Tags: java, gemfire, geode

I am using Apache Geode in one of my web applications.
I am using Custom class as a value-constraint in Apache Geode cache-server.xml file.
If value-constraint is not specified in the XML file, then I am able to start the server. But if value-constraint is specified then while running the server I am getting below error

**Exception in thread "main" org.apache.geode.cache.CacheXmlException: While reading Cache XML file:/C:/localfolder/cache-server.xml. Could not load value-constraint class: myPackage.Test, caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myPackage.Test**

Below is my startserver.bat file contents

> gfsh start server --server-port=12000 --dir=C:\localfolder\server
> --name=server123 --hostname-for-clients=***"someHost"*** --initial-heap=500m --max-heap=500m --bind-address=***"someAddress"*** --properties-file=gemfire.properties --server-properties-file=gfsecurity.properties --classpath=***"C:\localfolder\application.war"***

Please let me know

1. How to provide a custom class objects as a key-value constraint in the XML file?
2. How to use war file, in the server start process?

Answer (score 1):

The classpath (*Gfsh* option, and in general, to the `java` launcher) cannot refer to a WAR file; must be a JAR file (containing your application domain classes).

WAR files and JAR files have similar, but significantly different formats.

Comment: Yes correct.
I have resolved the issue by adding the Jar file in the classpath.